# Gradient from non-trainable weights function

Tags: machine-learning, backpropagation, gradient-descent, loss-function

I'm trying to implement a self-written loss function. My pipeline is as follows

**x *->* {constant computation} = x_feature *->* machine learning training *->* y_feature *->* {constant computation} = y_produced**

These "*constant computations*" are necessary to bring out the differences between the desired o/p and produced o/p.

So if I take the L2 norm of the y_produced and y_original, how should I incorporate this loss in the original loss.

Please Note that `y_produced` has a different dimension than `y_feature`.

Comment: what is your original loss? which language you are using? if you have two loss variable, you can simple add them.

Comment: My original loss functions deal with the y_feature and x_feature, but I'm not getting the desired training by using those loss values so I'm amplifying their effect using constant computations, which changes the dimension as well. These dimension changes are not an option. Language is Python and whole setup is in tensorflow.  @WasiAhmad

Comment: To be more specific these constant computations involve Fourier transforms and a little more @WasiAhmad

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using **differentiable** operations there is no difference between "constant transformations" and "learnable ones". There is no such distinction, look even at the linear layer of a neural net

```
f(x) = sigmoid( W * x + b )
```

is it constant or learnable? W and b are trained, but "sigmoid" is not, yet gradient flows the same way, no matter if something is a variable or not. In particular gradient wrt. to x is the same for

```
g(x) = sigmoid( A * x + c )
```

where A and c are constants.

The only problem you will encounter is using non-differentiable operations, such as: argmax, sorting, indexing, sampling etc. these operations do not have a well defined gradient thus you cannot directly use first order optimisers with them. As long as you stick with the differentiable ones - the problem described does not really exist - there is no difference between "constant transromations" and any other transformations - no matter change of the size etc.

Comment: I'm writing the whole computation in tensorflow right now, will ask for more help if that code involves something not differentiable. 
If that function involves something non-differentiable, we won't introduce those gradient right?

Comment: Gradient should become None, however there might be also implemented to constantly return 0 which might be more tricky. In either way you end up with *improper* optimisation then. It is not 'just a missing bit', it would actually lead to no convergence guarantees (if you have some non-differentiable path in your model, gradient descent can fail to learn anything, it can cycle, blow up etc.)